# how to read new-line from a textarea in a form with PHP?

Tags: php, html

How can I read the New-line so that when users fill in a text-area inside my form, and then hit submit, the text is displayed exactly the same way as they wrote it?

I should mention I read in the variables from the form with POST method in my php file.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The newline character in PHP is presented by the string `"\n"`.

If you want to reproduce the newlines of your users input in HTML, you have to convert every `\n` to a `<br />`. You could do that by hand or use the function [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) in such a way:

```
echo nl2br($_POST['input']);
```

Comment: don’t forget to sanitize `$_POST['input']` before with something like `htmlspecialchars`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function.

Example from documentation:

> ```
> <?php echo nl2br("foo isn't\n bar"); ?>
> ```
>
> The above example will output:
>
> `foo isn't<br />  bar`